# How to get GPS details of an device

Tags: java, gps

I have an requirement to be implemented, I used to track the position of the device using the GPS. Do java provide any api or any opensource api available for tracking the GPS system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaGPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javagps/) seems to do what you need:

> JavaGPS is a Java-only base library that enables access to GPS devices
>   from within any Java application.